# Finding the explicit formula for the sequence $a_{n+1}=a_{n}^2-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Consider the following sequence defined by
$$a_0=r, \quad a_{n+1}=a_{n}^2-1$$
where $r$ is just some real number. Here is some values
$$a_1=r^2-1, \quad a_2=r^4-2r^2, \quad a_3=r^8-4r^6+4r^4-1$$
$$a_4=r^{16}-8r^{14}+24r^{12}-32r^{10}+14r^8+8r^6-8r^4$$
The main problem with this sequence is that I can't see any pattern at all, except that the for odd $n$ there is a $(-1)$ at the end, and for even $n$ the powers of $r$ start by $n^2$ then $n^2-2$ all the way up to $n$.

I have no idea about the coefficients and the alternating signs.

Of course, once the pattern is revealed it's easy to prove it by induction, I think.

Comment: Do you expect an explicit formula to exist? E.g. if this is an exercise from a textbook, there is reason to believe such a formula exists; but if this is from elsewhere, it is very probable that there is no elementary explicit formula for this sequence.

Comment: Why do you expect a pattern?

Comment: Well it's not an exercise from a textbook, I've just been playing around and thought of it @Trebor

Comment: AFAIK only two types of quadratic recurrences can be solved: $a_{n+1}=a_n^2$, $a_{n+1}=2a_n^2 - 1$ and their equivalents.

Comment: There is a pattern if $a_{n+1}=2a_n^2-1,$ based on Chebyshev polynomials. Then $a_n=T_{2^n}(r).$

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK only two types of quadratic recurrences can be solved: $a_{n+1}=a_n ^2$, $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}^2 - 1$ and their equivalents. The first one should be obvious for you. The second one is solved by fiddling with $\cos (2^n c)$ or $\cosh (2^n c)$.

However, you can get away if $r$ is an integer. (I'll just deal with large $r$, the case with small $r$'s is evident.) You get $a_n = \left\lfloor c^{2^n}\right\rfloor$ for some $c$. This can be proved using basic properties of the floor function $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$, and $c$ is guaranteed to exist by the nested interval theorem.